# WEC 7.0 platform builder OS design build errors

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, platform-builder

I installed WEC 7.0 platform builder on my PC and trying to run the OS design into it. It reflects some errors and I couldn't find out what are the errors? Here are the error messages and warnings.

Errors:

```
Error   24  Error(s) in directory "C:\WINCE700\platform\P1230_CE\SRC\Services\Radio\".C:\WINCE700\build.log

Error   25  NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE700\OSDesigns\P1230_Mini\P1230_Mini\Wince700\P1230_CE_x86_Retail\cesysgen\oak\lib\x86\retail\radiogdi.lib'   C:\WINCE700\build.log   

Error   26  TargetExpLibFiles  -nologo BUILDMSG=Stop.  BUILDROOT=C:\WINCE700\platform\P1230_CE LINKONLY=1 NOPASS0=1 failed - rc = 2.    C:\WINCE700\build.log   

Error   27  BLDDEMO: ERROR: There were errors building cebase.  C:\WINCE700\build.log
```

Warnings:

```
C:\WINCE700\platform\common\src\x86\common\startup\base\: Missing source file: startup.asm. C:\WINCE700\build.log   
C:\WINCE700\platform\common\src\x86\common\startup\base\: Missing source file: reboot.asm.  C:\WINCE700\build.log
```

1. Are there any files missing or any .MSI file I need to install?
2. Which are the files I need after installing WEC 7.0 platform builder?

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Error   24  Error(s) in directory "C:\WINCE700\platform\P1230_CE\SRC\Services\Radio\".C:\WINCE700\build.log

Error   25  NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE700\OSDesigns\P1230_Mini\P1230_Mini\Wince700\P1230_CE_x86_Retail\cesysgen\oak\lib\x86\retail\radiogdi.lib'   C:\WINCE700\build.log
```

means that Platform Builder was unable to build the project in ...SRC\Services\Radio because that project depends on a library (radiogdi.lib), which does not exist and Platform Builder does not know how to create.

So the issue seems to be that radiogdi.lib has not been built.

I am not familiar with this particular BSP, so can only give general advice on what to try:

- Check `C:\WINCE700\build.log` for more details on the error
- Ensure that all [Platform Builder updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/dn205267.aspx) have been installed
- Verify that the BSP was not modified locally (and thus should be expected to build)
- Use `Clean Sysgen`, found in `Build | Advanced Build Commands`, to perform the initial build
- Examine the BSP documentation to see if all requirements are met. For instance, are all required Catalog Items included in the OS Design? Any dependencies on third-party products?

For a more specific answer, please update the question to specify:

- The BSP used (I don't remember the P1230_CE platform being part of a standard PB7.0 install)
- Whether a sample or a custom OS Design was used
- Modifications made, if any, to source code or OS Design
- Which command was used to start the build